# Uniqueness constraint on cross between two rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm creating a (postgres) table that has:

CREATE TABLE workers (id INT PRIMARY KEY, deleted_at DATE, account_id INT)

I'd like to have a uniqueness constraint only across workers that have not been deleted. Is there a good way to achieve this in sql? As an example:

```
id | date | account_id
1 | NULL | 1
# valid, was deleted
2 | yesterday | 1
# invalid, dup account
# 3 | NULL | 1
```

Comment: Don't use the MySQL tag for postgres questions, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want what Postgres calls a "partial index" (and other databases call a filtered index):

```
create unique index idx_workers_account_id on workers(account_id)
    where deleted_at is null;
```

[Here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/indexes-partial.html) is the documentation on this feature.